# Maclaurin series of two functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Maclaurin series of the following two functions:

$ f(z)=\cos(z)+\frac{1}{z^2+1}\qquad g(z)=e^{z^2}+\sin(3z)$.

Computing the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ and calculating them in zero, I cannot find a clear relation that would make it possible to write down the series (the derivatives become very complex very quickly). Is there any other way that I am ignoring to find these series that doesn't involve computing the derivatives?

Comment: Just use the series expansion of sine, cosine, exponential etc.

Comment: Also the geometric series expansion for $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first function:
$$\cos(z)+\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\sum_0^{+\infty}\frac{(-)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}=\sum_0^{+\infty}\frac{(-)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\sum_0^{+\infty}(-z^2)^n\\
=\sum_0^{+\infty}\frac{(-)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\sum_0^{+\infty}(-)^nz^{2n}$$
observing that $\dfrac{1}{1+z^2}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus\{\pm i\}$, so we have expanded the fnzion in the annulus $\{|z|<1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the second one:   $e^{z^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac {z^{2n}}{n!}$ and $\sin 3z=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{(-1)^n(3z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Add 'em up.

Comment: We used the very nice fact: a power series that converges to a function is automatically the Taylor series of that function (inside the radius of convergence).